# How to determine height of a triangle knowing various segment lenghts

Tags: geometry

[image]

How can I determine the height of dotted black line if I know the value of a, b, c, d and e?

I have tried triangle similarity, but I couldn't solve it, I thought that I could work it out with angles, but I failed. All I could do was the Pythagoras theorem to find the remaining side of the triangle with sides a, b and with sides c, d.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let $e=x+y$. From similar right triangles on both sides,

$$\frac{h}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\frac {x+b}{b}; \>\>\>\>\>\frac{h}{\sqrt{c^2-d^2}}=\frac {y+d}{d}$$

Rearrange to get

$$x+y=e= \frac{hb}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} + \frac{hd}{\sqrt{c^2-d^2}} -b-d$$

Solve for the height,

$$h = \frac{b+d+e}{\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} + \frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2-d^2}} }$$